# Support Emojis on XML

Tags: ios, xml, emoji

well  i am creating a chat app but the retrieving mode is xml
if someone sends an emoji the xml does not recognize it it shows like a '?' symbol
I hope someone can helpme solving this :)
Thanks
Santiago

Comment: have you solved your issue?

Comment: You can encode the emoji or (best solution) you can use json which is easier and quicker than xml